# How to push my new branch to original repo

Tags: git, github, push, git-fork

I forked a repo and worked on one of its branches. From there, I created a new branch, e.g. newB1 and pushed the changes there. I see the newB1 in my forked repo, but it does not appear to the original repo. How do I push this new branch to the original report as well?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork

Comment: Or just create a second remote and push to it.

Answer (score 4):

Everybody can create a fork.
But only the repo owner/maintainer has permission to push commits to the original repo.

So you have to create a pull request, to notify the owner/maintainer about the change in your fork.
The maintainer then does a review, and decides whether to push if your change is worthy.

This is the workflow, to keep the quality of the original repository.

Comment: How exactly do you publish a new branch on upstream with a pull request? PRs merge or rebase one branch into another.